# Need a bit of help with indexed sets/collection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with the following question. I just can't seem to make any sense out of it. Any productive help will be appreciated!

Let $A_k$ be a set for each positive integer $k$. Define another collection of sets $B_k$:

$B_1 = A_1$

$B_2 = A_2 \setminus A_1$

and so on:

$B_k = A_k \setminus \cup_{t<k}A_t$

Prove that

1. The sets $B_k$ are pairwise disjoint
2. $\cup_{t \leq k} A_t = \cup_{t\leq k}B_t$ for each positive integer $k$
3. $\cup_{t \geq 1} A_t = \cup_{t \geq 1}B_t$

Comment: What is "∪t"? Also, you should typeset your question in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It would help  if we told us what difficulties you are having

Comment: Well, I can't seem to solve parts 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure I'm understanding you we have $B_k=A_k \setminus (\bigcup_{t<k} A_t)$? If this is the case, I notice that $B_k$ and $\bigcup_{t<k} A_t$ are disjoint and $B_{i}\subset \bigcup_{t<k} A_k$ (def. of $B_i$) for all $i<k$. Also, we certainly have $\bigcup_{t<k} B_t \subset \bigcup_{t \le k} A_t$. We just need to show that nothing from $A_t$, $t\le k$ is being left out.

Comment: A lot of the above comes just by noticing that nothing in $B_k$ is not in $A_k$ ($B_k \subset A_k$).